# Java contains vs anyMatch behaviour

Tags: java, java-stream, equality

If I have a `Name` object and have an `ArrayList` of type `Name` (`names`), and I want to ascertain whether my list of names contains a given `Name` object (`n`), I could do it two ways:

```
boolean exists = names.contains(n);
```

or

```
boolean exists = names.stream().anyMatch(x -> x.equals(n));
```

I was considering if these two would behave the same and then thought about what happens if n was assigned `null`?

For contains, as I understand, if the argument is `null`, then it returns `true` if the list contains `null`. How would I achieve this `anyMatch` - would it be by using `Objects.equals(x, n)`?

If that is how it works, then which approach is more efficient - is it `anyMatch` as it can take advantage of laziness and parallelism?

Comment: What is `names` type?

Comment: If `names` is indeed an `ArrayList`, then I'd guess the performance would be similar. But if it's something like a `HashSet` then a `contains` call would be almost certainly more efficient (as it doesn't actually need to loop through the elements).

Comment: @JoachimSauer He *said* that it is an `ArrayList`. It is at least reasonable to assume that this is true.

Comment: @Marco13: I'm not questioning it, just giving a tiny bit more information than asked for. Answering the specific narrow question alone would possibly give a wrong picture.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Agreed, it might be worth to point out this difference (as Zbynek Vyskovsky - kvr000 also did in his answer)

Comment: @Marco13 It is worth mentioning in my humble opinion.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The problem with the stream-based version is that **if** the collection (and thus its stream) contains `null` elements, then the predicate will throw a `NullPointerException` when it tries to call `equals` on this `null` object.

This could be avoided with

```
boolean exists = names.stream().anyMatch(x -> Objects.equals(x, n));
```

But there is no practical advantage to be expected for the stream-based solution in this case. Parallelism might bring an advantage for *really* large lists, but one should not casually throw in some `parallel()` here and there assuming that it *may* make things faster. First, you should clearly identify the actual bottlenecks.

And in terms of readability, I'd prefer the first, classical solution here. If you want to check whether the list of `names.contains(aParticularValue)`, you should do this - it just reads like prose and makes the intent clear.

> EDIT

Another advantage of the `contains` approach was mentioned in the comments and in the other answer, and that may be worth mentioning here: If the type of the `names` collection is later changed, for example, to be a `HashSet`, then you'll get the faster `contains`-check (with O(1) instead of O(n)) for free - without changing any other part of the code. The stream-based solution would then still have to iterate over *all* elements, and this could have a significantly lower performance.

Comment: Also: *if* performance becomes relevant, then switching to a different data type is a way simpler way to improve performance than to throw parallelism at it (`LinkedHashSet` or similar, if the order needs to be maintained).

Comment: Nice quality content, indeed.

Answer (score 4):

They should provide the same result if `hashCode()` and `equals()` are written in reasonable way.

But the performance may be completely different. For Lists it wouldn't matter that much but for HashSet `contains()` will use `hashCode()` to locate the element and it will be done (most probably) in constant time. While with the second solution it will loop over all items and call a function so will be done in linear time.

If n is null, actually doesn't matter as usually `equals()` methods are aware of `null` arguments.

Comment: You're right that every `equals` method should check whether its *argument* is `null`. But here, the predicate might try to call the `equals` method on a `null` object, leading to an NPE

Comment: The String literal should be on the left side of the comparison, and you dont have to worry about NPE.